# How to get the number of elements returned from a function in Python

Tags: python, function

How I can get the number of elements returned from a function whithout execute it ? And may be also, know the type of these elements ?

I know i can do something like :

```
def foo ():
    return 'a', 2

handle = foo()
print len(handle)
>> 2
```

But here i need to execute my function ...

Comment: A simpler version of your question is "how to find out whether a function returns at all" ([Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Well, by (manually or maybe intelligently statically) examining the source of most non-pathological functions we can determine the return type if it halts. Of course in many cases that'll just be `object` due to type inference being hard in Python.

Comment: If you really want this sort of capability in python you could use a design by contract methodology (which can be achieved using PyContracts).  Then you are declaring input and output for each function.  I doubt this is actually what you want, but thought it worth mentioning ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't -- A function can return different numbers of arguments (stored in a single tuple) and different types of variables in that tuple depending on input or other factors.  consider the (silly) function:

```
def foo(arg):
    if arg:
       return 1,2
    else
       return "foo","bar","baz"
```

Now call it:

```
foo(1) # (1,2)
foo(0) # ("foo","bar","baz")
```

The only way to know what a function will return is to 1) read the source or 2) (If you're a trusting sort of person) read the documentation for the function :-).

Comment: If you wanted to make the example a bit crueler, you could make the function impure by replacing `if arg` with `if random.random() < 0.5`

Comment: @hobbs -- Sure I could.  But I think that would obscure the point. It doesn't have to be an impure function for it to be beyond the scope of the interpreter to know the type and size of the output.

Comment: @hobbs: if you want to be cruel you could: `def f(): while does_it_stop(f): pass` where `does_it_stop(f)` should return `True` if `f()` stops eventually.

Answer (score 2):

No. In general, all you can say is that a function returns exactly *one* object. That object can be a tuple, and that tuple can contain any number of objects. In your example, you are returning a tuple containing 2 objects

Consider this function

```
import random
def foo():
    choice = random.choice("abcd")
    if choice == "a":
        return 1,2,3       # Returns a tuple
    if choice == "b":
        return 4           # Returns an int
    if choice == "c":
        return "C"         # Returns a str
    if choice == "d":
        return None        # Returns None
```

Obviously you can't know the type of the return values

Comment: `dis.dis(foo)` provides some info.